# PrimeNG v10LTS fileUpload inserting p-message?

Tags: primeng

We just completed an upgrade from PrimeNG 8 to 10. We utilize the fileUpload component quite heavily in our app. Prior to upgrade, if someone tried to add an unsupported file type, an error message would appear below the input field and browse button. After the upgrade, there now appears to be a p-message component being inserted that shoves the browse button down below, as shown below:[image]

Does anyone know how to make it so the browse button stays where it is?

Thanks!